# Error during submission

Tags: xcode, submission

I just rewrote my whole project to Swift 2.0 because xcode 7 doesnt support 1.2. Everything is fine except submission. Xcode shows me following error and I have no idea what to do:

```
The archive did not contain <DVTFilePath:0x7f9a1672aac0:'/Users/Adam/Library/
Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-03/final_project 03.10.15 19.28.xcarchive/
BCSymbolMaps/989F2A46-2149-3CE5-AFD1-1614968AE31C.bcsymbolmap'> as expected.
```

I also get this one:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's likely you built your app with Enable Bitcode set to NO in build settings.

Then, in the app submission window, you had "include bitcode" checked, which is now at the bottom of the window. Uncheck that and it should submit. Enable bitcode in your build settings if you want to then submit with bitcode.

Answer (score 7):

You just **uncheck the "include app symbols..."** when you submit,it will
works.like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqmc3.png).

When I try the first answer,it works.but I want to enable bitcode in my app.So I found the answer below that can resolve this problem:
Visit https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729
It's seems a bug in Xcode that you can't check the "include app symbols" and "include bitcode" both.