# Why won't Alamofire.framework code sign during the 'Preparing Archive' process in Xcode 7.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode7, alamofire

When archiving my iOS project in Xcode 7.1, during the uploading process, the 'Preparing Archive' process is hung on 'Codesigning Alamofire.framework...'. It'll do this until my Mac falls asleep.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is bitCode option enabled?

Comment: Currently, it's not.

Comment: Have you updated the Alamofire to 3.0?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Alamofire 3.0.

Comment: Now try to delete "Derived Data" and "Clean the build", then try to upload

Comment: So I made sure the bitCode was disabled form the build settings, cleaned the project, and deleted the derived data. It's still hanging on the Alamofire.framework during uploading validation...

Comment: Enable the bitcode, if you have used all the latest version Frameworks

Comment: When enabling bitcode, it get this error: The archive did not contain <DVTFilePath: ... as expected.

Comment: I read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925498/error-during-submission that it generally occurs when you've set it to no, but when it's enabled it's happening on my end.

Comment: I am not getting this error! Just now uploaded the app!

Comment: Interesting, it's telling me my archive is not valid because the .ipa file does not exist.

Comment: don't use AppLoader to uplaod,

Comment: I'm new to the submission process, if you don't use the app loader via Xcode, what else do you use?

Comment: Xcode Archive process